# Javafx - How can I delay the display of a new line in my textarea?

Tags: java, javafx

So I got this new game I am coding. 
Long story short, there is a textarea in my GUI which acts as an event displayer. When you fight a monster, this textarea is used to display lines of text such as "You deal 3 damages to skeleton" or "Skeleton casts fireball on you and hit you for 5 damages".

The code works in a way so that the monster attacks after you. So as soon as you hit the "Attack" button, both the line saying what you did and the line saying what the monster did appears at the same time in the textarea. Like if the monster could hit you at the speed of light right after you hit it.

What I want to do is to delay the display of the monster's line. So that when I hit the "Attack" button, the textarea displays the line of what I did, then wait a second and then displays the monster's line.

I tried using the Thread.sleep() method, but all it does is pausing the UI for 1 second and then both lines appear in the textarea.

```
private void attackBareFists() {

    if (initPJ > enemyINIT) { // Player has more initiative ->
                                // Player attacks first
        turnPlayerBareFists(); // This method will display the player's line

        if (!endTurn()) { // endTurn() checks that the player or the monster 
                          // are still alive before continuing the fight
            delay();
            turnMonster(); // This method will display the monster's line
            endTurn();
        }
    } ... // The code continues, but it's the same as above except monster attacks first
}

/**
 * Wait for some time
 */
private void delay(){

}
```

What should I put in delay()? This is where I've tried Thread.sleep(1000). And like I said, doing so caused the code of turnPlayerBareFists() and turnMonster() to be executed after delay(). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! I suggest using something like this:

```
public static void delay(long delayMs, Runnable toRun){
    Thread t = new Thread(() ->{
        try { Thread.sleep(delayMs); }catch(InterruptedException ignored){}
        Platform.runLater(toRun);
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

This way, you can specify exactly how long the delay should between the call to `delay()` and when your code should be executed. Essentially you pass a `Runnable` containing whatever code you want to run as the second argument of the method.

For example, this would mean that your the monster's turn would be represented as such:

```
if(!endTurn())
    delay(1000, ()->{ turnMonster(); endTurn(); });
```

**If, for some reason, you don't want to use lambdas (the "()->" things), you can use this:**

```
public static void delay(long delayMs, Runnable toRun){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try { Thread.sleep(delayMs); }catch(InterruptedException ignored){}
            Platform.runLater(toRun);
        }
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

And your monster code would look like this:

```
if(!endTurn())
    delay(1000, new Runnable(){ public void run(){ turnMonster(); endTurn(); } });
```

If you're wondering, `Platform` refers to `javafx.application.Platform` and the `runLater()` method will always post the given Runnable to the JavaFX thread, so it's safe to pass it code that manipulates the UI.

Comment: Thanks! This worked exactly as I wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I think a better/more consistent way to achieve this is by using timers. You could use any java implementation, though javafx itself provides several mechanism for timed events.

One way is the TimeLine

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
    Duration.millis(1000),
    ae -> doSkellyTurn()),
    new KeyFrame(
    Duration.millis(1000 + 1000), // as mentioned by fabien, the time offset is relative to the 'start()' method, not to its previous keyframe!
    ae -> endSkellyTurn()));
timeline.play();
```

The above way is also the basics for [javafx animations (as you can read in the documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html)

[This blog](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2014/06/04/timers-in-javafx-and-reactfx.html) shows some more examples of how you can accomplish timed tasks. (Ps. It uses reactFX as well!)